# Suspend or Hibernate Kali linux after being inactive for a while

Tags: linux, debian, kali-linux, suspend, hibernate

I have an **Hp ProBook 450G1** with a 500GB HDD and i run Kali linux. Whenever i am not actively using my pc, and i leave it on for a while and i am not connected to power, my laptop remains on which causes it to run low on battery power.

So i want to know if it is possible to make kali automatically suspend or hibernate my pc itself if i am in active for a particular amount of time

Comment: Kali is not designed to be used as a desktop Linux distro. Although it *can* be installed doesn't mean it *should*. It's mainly used as a live session or in a VM, not installed in bare metal. Obligatory reading: https://www.kali.org/docs/introduction/should-i-use-kali-linux/

Comment: I know. I use it for work. So can you help

Comment: Kali is not for work unless the work is pentesting. Anyway the settings you're looking for are the same as in any Debian.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get Kali Linux to not go to sleep?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/162989/how-to-get-kali-linux-to-not-go-to-sleep)

Comment: I want the system to suspend or hibernate if it is powered on and it isn't being actively used after say like 5 minutes